# Range of Formula

Tags: functions

This is the formula for Henderson Seller's Lack of Cohesion:

```
(M – sum(MF)/F)(M-1)
```

The range should be [0-2], however I don't understand exactly why. What is the mathematical justification behind this?

- M is the number of methods in class (both static and instance methods
  are counted, it includes also constructors, properties
  getters/setters, events add/remove methods).
- F is the number of instance fields in the class.
- MF is the number of methods of the class accessing a particular
  instance field.
- Sum(MF) is the sum of MF over all instance fields of the class.

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to express it as such.